# Поиск в глубину реализация

Tags: графы, c++

Здравствуйте. У меня проблема с элементарным поиском в глубину.Я только начал изучать графы и не могу реализовать. Вот сам код http://pastebin.com/aT0LREhc Заранее огромное спасибо.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
vector <vector<int>> g;       // граф
int n;                        // число вершин

vector<bool> used;

void dfs(int v)
{
    used[v] = true;
    cout << v;
    for (vector<int>::iterator i = g[v].begin(); i != g[v].end(); ++i)
        if (!used[*i])
            dfs(*i);
}

int main()
{
    n = 4;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        dfs(i);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Либо это копипаста из готового проекта, либо автор не проф. на C++, зачем-то понадобилось число вершин, и куча ненужных сишных хедеров.

Вот как бы у меня выглядели первые строки:
<pre><code>#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector <vector<int>> g;       // граф'
<pre><code>
+ 'vector<bool> used' вынесен за пределы фунцкции... Странно. Его можно было, как 'static' объявить.

Comment: Написан какой-то фрагментарный, неясный говнокод. Очень интересно обращение к элементам вектора. Оно вообще безопасно? Где вообще код заполнения графа???

Answer (score 1):

По коду: неплохо было бы в начале заполнить граф вершинами/ребрами).

А теперь маленький совет: 
Если хотите использовать графы, то лучше использовать *отличную* библиотеку из [Boost](http://www.boost.org) -- BGL(вот [ссылка](http://www.rsdn.ru/res/book/cpp/bgl.xml) на книгу), в ней поиск в глубину уже реализован, а также в ширину, алгоритмы поиска пути и многое другое!

Ну, а если хочется реализовать эти алгоритмы самому, то, ИМХО, лучше использовать нормальное представление графа из BGL, а не этот список смежности.

p.s. Не забывайте про принцип **DRY**(Don't Repeat Yourself)!

**UPD**:
Вот код примера из `dfs.cpp`, смотрите примерный вывод и код функции main, ИМХО, очень даже лаконично.

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/visitors.hpp>

/*
  This calculates the discover finishing time.

  Sample Output

  Tree edge: 0 --> 2
  Tree edge: 2 --> 1
  Back edge: 1 --> 1
  Tree edge: 1 --> 3
  Back edge: 3 --> 1
  Tree edge: 3 --> 4
  Back edge: 4 --> 0
  Back edge: 4 --> 1
  Forward or cross edge: 2 --> 3
  1 10
  3 8
  2 9
  4 7
  5 6

 */

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

template <class VisitorList>
struct edge_categorizer : public dfs_visitor<VisitorList> {
  typedef dfs_visitor<VisitorList> Base;

  edge_categorizer(const VisitorList& v = null_visitor()) : Base(v) { }

  template <class Edge, class Graph>
  void tree_edge(Edge e, Graph& G) {
    cout << "Tree edge: " << source(e, G) <<
      " --> " <<  target(e, G) << endl;
    Base::tree_edge(e, G);
  }
  template <class Edge, class Graph>
  void back_edge(Edge e, Graph& G) {
    cout << "Back edge: " << source(e, G)
         << " --> " <<  target(e, G) << endl;
    Base::back_edge(e, G);
  }
  template <class Edge, class Graph>
  void forward_or_cross_edge(Edge e, Graph& G) {
    cout << "Forward or cross edge: " << source(e, G)
         << " --> " <<  target(e, G) << endl;
    Base::forward_or_cross_edge(e, G);
  }
};
template <class VisitorList>
edge_categorizer<VisitorList>
categorize_edges(const VisitorList& v) {
  return edge_categorizer<VisitorList>(v);
}

int 
main(int , char* [])
{

  using namespace boost;

  typedef adjacency_list<> Graph;

  Graph G(5);
  add_edge(0, 2, G);
  add_edge(1, 1, G);
  add_edge(1, 3, G);
  add_edge(2, 1, G);
  add_edge(2, 3, G);
  add_edge(3, 1, G);
  add_edge(3, 4, G);
  add_edge(4, 0, G);
  add_edge(4, 1, G);

  typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
  typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertices_size_type size_type;

  std::vector<size_type> d(num_vertices(G));  
  std::vector<size_type> f(num_vertices(G));
  int t = 0;
  depth_first_search(G, visitor(categorize_edges(
                     make_pair(stamp_times(&d[0], t, on_discover_vertex()),
                               stamp_times(&f[0], t, on_finish_vertex())))));

  std::vector<size_type>::iterator i, j;
  for (i = d.begin(), j = f.begin(); i != d.end(); ++i, ++j)
    cout << *i << " " << *j << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: > Естественно эта штука не скомпилируется, т.к. у вектора этот оператор не предусмотрен!

в новой версии C++ это пофиксили. [Угловые скобки][1]

 [1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#.D0.A3.D0.B3.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.BA.D0.B8

Comment: @gecube, извините не знал, пост пофиксил

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<bool> was; // вектор, в котором мы храним, были ли мы в вершине
vector<vector<int> > graph; // вектор, в котором мы храним наш граф в виде списка смежности

void dfs( int v){
    if (was[v]){ // если мы были в данной вершине, то уходим из нее
        return;
    }
    was[v] = 1; // говорим что уже были в этой вершине
    for (auto i : graph[v]){ 
        dfs(i); // запускаем новый dfs от каждого соседа
    }
}

int main() {
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m; // считываем количество вершин и ребер
    graph.resize(n);
    was.resize(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        was[i] = 0; // говорим что мы нигде не были
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        a--; b--; //Обычно во входных данных вершину нумеруются с единицы
        graph[a].push_back(b); //считываем весь ориентированный граф
    }
    dfs(0); // запускаем дфс от начальной вершины, за которую взяли нулевую
    return 0;
}
```